# $X,Y$ are independent stanard normal variables. What is $E[\frac{X^2}{Y^2}]$?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared

If $X,Y$ are independent standard normal variables, then $X^2, Y^2$ are independent chi-squared r.v with 1 degree of freedom, i.e. $X^2 \in \chi^2_1, Y^2 \in \chi^2_1$.

I am trying to find the mean and variance of $\frac{X^2}{Y^2}$, i.e. $E[\frac{X^2}{Y^2}], Var[[\frac{X^2}{Y^2}]$

After a quick research on the Internet, I found that $\frac{X^2}{Y^2}$ is F-distribution with 1 degree of freedom, i.e. $\frac{X^2}{Y^2} \sim F(1,1)$. But I couldn't find the mean and variance for it. What I found is that for $F(d_1,d_2)$
$$E[\frac{X^2}{Y^2}]= \frac{d_2}{d_2-2}, \text{for } d_2>2$$
$$Var[\frac{X^2}{Y^2}] = \frac{2d_2^2(d_1+d_2-2)}{d_1(d_2-2)(d_2-4)}, \text{for }d_2>4 $$
But here $$d_1=d_2=1$$

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: $\frac {X^{2}} {Y^{2}}$ has infinite mean and (the variance is not defined).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you mind pointing me to some references?

Comment: $E\frac {X^{2}} {Y^{2}}=(EX^{2})( E\frac 1 {Y^{2}})$ and it is easy to see that $E\frac 1 {Y^{2}}=\infty$.

Comment: It may be obvious, but why $E\frac{1}{Y^2} = \infty$? Thank you.

Comment: $\int \phi (y)/y^{2}dy=\infty$. Just look at  the integral in a neighborhood of $0$.  ($\phi$ is the standard normal density).